# Android ListView with CheckBox can distinguish the click

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to create a ListView with CheckBox's...Th ListView should allow the user to both select an item or open that item to select other choice inside it. In other words, the ListView should be able to distinguish between the click on the checkbox and the click on the item itself.

I tried to implement it using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice but this one allows me to only check the checkbox even if I click outside the checkbox (on the item).

anyone can help?
Here's my code,

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {  

ListView directoryList;


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final ArrayList<String> contacts = new ArrayList<String>();
    contacts.add("zaid");
    contacts.add("hazem");
    contacts.add("Oubai");


    directoryList= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.directoryList);


    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,
                                  contacts);


    directoryList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    directoryList.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    directoryList.setClickable(true);



}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {




}
```

}

Comment: I had a similar problem and I solved iy with an OnClickListener in the adapter itself. Not the cleanest way but it worked

Comment: okay, can you please show me how you did that in the code? thanks

Comment: shubhayu's answer provides a better example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a customized array adapter. In your getView(), get a hold of your checkbox and set the OnCheckedChangeListener()

Here is a tutorial on how you can make your own custom adapter. The example has a clickable textbox but you can change it to work for a checkbox.

http://www.shubhayu.com/android/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-customized-items

Comment: Thanks....Here's a better tutorial
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-convertview-in-getview-to-make.html

Comment: It's good but it doesn't show how to add a listener in the adapter. :)

Comment: your tutorial was very useful to me but it doesn't show that class MyCustomAdapter is being overridden. It just suddenly overrides a method which made me going crazy...Thanks anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :) I'll add that part. I had actually added the complete working code but I guess I should have mentioned it in the tutorial too.

Comment: oh...so you are the one who made that tutorial....that's a Great job, keep it up.